# Hovering on a variables in Chrome dev tools is not showing the current value?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

On hovering a variable in Chrome dev tools, after putting the debugger in the .js file, the current value of that variable is not showing.

I'm using Chrome version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: This is a bug which will be fixed in the next version of Chrome. Meanwhile use Chrome Canary.

Comment: Hopefully will be fixed, but wasn't fixed in the last version. Upvote this issue to get it more attention: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/22882968?hl=en

Comment: The problem has unfortunately resurfaced (Sep 2022).

Answer (score 1):

As has been rightly pointed by @wOxxOm and @adam0101, this is a bug and the Chrome team is addressing it.

For now, I'm using Chrome Canary https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/, which seems to be working perfectly fine.

Comment: The problem has unfortunately resurfaced (Sep 2022).

Comment: Same here. I also have the bug now.

Comment: This is the problem for me too last few weeks, but you can go to console and print your variables there. Not perfect but temporary solution for now XD

Comment: yes I got it a few weeks ago too

Comment: Ya it has resurfaced. Any solutions ?